# no se ha encontrado la clase principal

Tags: java

Hola al momento de compilar el ARCHIVO DE PRUEBA en la consola con `javacc` me sale

> "Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal
>   ProyectoCompi.java"

Este es mi ARCHIVO JJ:

```
>PARSER_BEGIN(ProyectoCompi)
>class ProyectoCompi{
>   public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
>       try{
>           ProyectoCompi analizador = new ProyectoCompi(System.in);
>           analizador.programa();
>       }catch(ParseException e){
>           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
>           System.out.println("Analizador: Se han encontrado errores en el analisis");
>       }
>   }
>}
>PARSER_END(ProyectoCompi)
>
>TOKEN:{
>   <MAIN: "public static void main()"> {System.out.println("Main -> " + image);}
>}
>
>TOKEN:{
>   <LPAREN: "(">{System.out.println("PARENTIZQ -> " + image);}
>   |<RPAREN: ")">{System.out.println("PARENTDER -> " + image);}
>   |<LBRACE: "{">{System.out.println("LLAVEIZQ -> " + image);}
>   |<RBRACE: "}">{System.out.println("LLAVEDER -> " + image);}
>   |<COMA: ",">{System.out.println("COMA -> " + image);}
>   |<SEMICOLON: ";">{System.out.println("PUNTO Y COMA -> " + image);}
>}
>
>TOKEN:{
>   <ASIGNACION: "=">{System.out.println("ASIGNACION -> " + image + "\r\n");}
>   |<SUMA: "+">{System.out.println("SUMA -> " + image + "\r\n");}
>   |<RESTA: "-">{System.out.println("RESTA -> " + image + "\r\n");}
>   |<PRODUCTO: "*">{System.out.println("SUMA -> " + image + "\r\n");}
>   |<IMPRIMIR: "imprimir ">{System.out.println("IMPRIMIR -> " + image + "\r\n");}
>}
>
>TOKEN:{
>   <COMPLEJO: "Complejo ">{System.out.println("COMPLEJO -> " + image);}
>   |<NUMBER: (["0"-"9"])+>{System.out.println("NUMERO -> " + image);}
>   |<IDENTIFIER: (["a"-"z","A"-"Z"])+>{System.out.println("IDENTIFICADOR   -> " + image + "\r\n");}
>}
>
>SKIP:{
>   " " | "\r\n" | "\t" | "\t\t" | "\t\t\t"
>}
>
>void Programa():
>{}
>{
>   <MAIN><LBRACE>Sentencias()<RBRACE><EOF>
>}
>
>void Sentencias():
>{}
>{
>   DeclaracionLocal()
>}
>
>void DeclaracionLocal():
>{}
>{
>
>   <COMPLEJO><IDENTIFIER>(DeclaracionSimple() | DeclaracionCompleja() | DeclaracionCombinada())  <SEMICOLON> recursivo()
>}
>
>void recursivo():
>{}
>{
>   DeclaracionLocal()
>}
>
>void DeclaracionSimple():
>{}
>{
>   (<COMA><IDENTIFIER>)*
>}
>
>void DeclaracionCompleja():
>{}
>{
>   <LPAREN><NUMBER><COMA><NUMBER><RPAREN> (<COMA><IDENTIFIER> <LPAREN><NUMBER><COMA><NUMBER><RPAREN>)*
>}

>void DeclaracionCombinada():
>{}
>{
>   ((DeclaracionSimple() | DeclaracionCompleja())<COMA>)*((DeclaracionSimple() | DeclaracionCompleja()))
>}
```

ARCHIVO DE PRUEBA:

```
    public static void main(){
        Complejo a;
        Complejo a,b;
        Complejo a,b(5,4);
        Complejo a(5,4);
        Complejo a(5,4),b;
        Complejo a,b(5,4),c;
        Complejo a(5,4),b,c(6,5);
    }
```

Comment: Si estas compilando por consola, revisa el paquete. puede estar incorrecto o tal vez no lo necesites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este error

> "Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal"

puede tener varias causas, relacionadas a que el compilador simplemente no encuentra la clase.

- El nombre de la clase no es el correcto.
- El paquete no es correcto.

Ejecuta `javacc` en el folder que contiene el archivo `.jj`